# Entity framework, поле DbGeography в сущности

Tags: c#, entity-framework, миграция, spatial

Использую codeFirst и хочу загонять в бд пространственные данные, например полигон, поэтому есть таблица типа

```
 /// <summary>
/// Класс для объектов которые могут быть автоматически импортированы
/// </summary>
[Table("NamedGeoObjects")]
public class NamedGeoObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Международное название сущности
    /// </summary>
    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Локализованное русское название сущности
    /// </summary>
    [Column("name_ru")]
    public string NameRu { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// geography
    /// </summary>
    [Column("geo")]
    public DbGeography _Geo { get; set; }

}
```

При попытке создать миграцию пишет ошибку. 
`Not supported edm type: Edm.Geography`
Есть ли какой то вариант напрямую напрямую работать с пространственными типами без прокладок из string?.

Comment: Посмотрите на атрибут `ComplexType`

Comment: пример привести можете?

Comment: чуть более подробно про [ComplexType](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/6.4.php), если это не то что Вы хотите, то опишите в вопросе более подробно что хотите  получить в итоге

Comment: нет комплекс это не то, я хочу получить в бд поле типа geometry(MultiPolygon,4326), и рабоать с ним напрямую (в sql это поле типа geography), а сейчас приходится через entity создавать поле строкового типа, и в самом классе преобразовывать в нужный тип, а хочется сразу из бд получить нужный тип